# Transparent part of png Image showing white colour

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a png image inside Image tag. Part of the image has transparent background. In my android phone it's showing white colour. I want the white part to be removed and make that transparent.

Here's my code -

```
export default class LoginScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style = {styles.topContainer}>
        <Image style = {styles.logoContainer}
        source = {require('../images/black_header.png')} />
      </View>
     </View>
    );
  }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  logoContainer: {
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
    width: null,
    height: 254,
  },
  container: {
    backgroundColor: "#f7f7f7"
  },
  topContainer: {
    backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)"
  }
});
```

Comment: Mention why down voted

Comment: It will have to show some background colour through the transparent image. Is it currently showing he light grey colour defined in the container style?

Comment: @RobWalker No. It's showing white colour.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you're having the same problem that me, but I had some similar issue and resolved it adding `StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject` to the `logoContainer`.

Answer (score -1):

write in image `style={{  position:'absolute'}}`